# Convert sql to linq using select max list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Help me please. how to convert this to Linq

```
select * from t_collect_op_dtl_kimper co 
where co.PTDHCARD_ID ='489144'
and kimper_id = (select max(kimper_id) from t_collect_op_dtl_kimper 
co1 where co.PTDHCARD_ID = co1.ptdhcard_id and co.model =co1.model)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not about teaching, it help solve problems with code. Try yourself first

Comment: You say that you are _stuck here_ that means you have tried already. Can you put what you have tried and which part of it you are not able to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
var result = t_collect_op_dtl_kimper
             .Where( x => x.PTDHCARD_ID == 489144 && 
                     x.kimper_id == t_collect_op_dtl_kimper
                     .Where( y => y.PTDHCARD_ID == x.PTDHCARD_ID && y.model == x.model ) 
                     .Max( y => y.kimper_id ) )
             .ToList();
```

Comment: How to accept an answer check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer query comprehension, you can pretty much translate the SQL directly:

```
var ans2 = from co in t_collect_op_dtl_kimper
           where co.PTDHCARD_ID == "489144" &&
                 co.kimper_id == (from co1 in t_collect_op_dtl_kimper
                                  where co.PTDHCARD_ID == co1.PTDHCARD_ID && co.model == co1.model
                                  select co1.kimper_id)
                                 .Max()
           select co;
```